# What kinds of batteries have the highest energy density?

Tags: batteries, watts, capacity

My question is, what kinds of batteries have the highest amount of watt hours per cm3? I know, comparatively, that for example li-ion batteries in phones generally have a higher capacity than, say, duracell rechargeable aa batteries. Preferably, I would prefer each individual battery to be under 5 volts, and not cost more than a hundred dollars.

Comment: The title asks about power density (watts/cm^3) but the text asks about energy density (watt hours/cm^3) . Pick one.

Comment: "Preferably, I would prefer each individual battery to be under 5 volts, and not cost more than a hundred dollars." - do you have a particular application in mind? Energy density is just one of many factors that you may have to consider.

Comment: Lithium, specifically Lithium Polymer, wins on terms of *power* density (several kW/liter) while Zinc Air wins in terms of *energy* density (~1500Wh/liter for real batteries, nearly 10'000 in theory). But Zn-Air is NOT a rechargeable chemistry and a LiPo might only last a couple dozen cycles at several kW/L power densities. Zn-Air has a limited life of <a month once exposed to air and LiPos have a bad habit of bursting into flames when provoked. Neither is particularly cheap and *every battery chemistry* I know is <5V per cell. Choose wisely.

Comment: The ones that cause the bigest explosions.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Batteries do not exist on a single line that measures say capacity. They exist in a "phase space" that includes capacity, robustness (how they put up with overcharge or overdischarge) and safety (ask Samsung). These are examples there may be more.

You have given the answer to your question the Li-ion batteries are by far the highest in pure capacity. However you need to take into account the other dimensions to get a really good answer.